# Equivalent for ServletContextListener in Play

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm new to server-side development and have been experimenting with the Play framework recently. And I'm curious to know if there is an equivalent of ServletContextListener in Play.  I found an [Application](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0.2/java/index.html) class and a [Plugin](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0.2/java/index.html) class from the Javadocs.

I want to start a bluetooth server from my web application when it starts and want to shut it down when the web app quits.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the [Global object](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/wiki/JavaGlobal): start your bluetooth server to the `onStart()` method, and stop it in the `onStop()` method.

```
public class Global extends GlobalSettings {

  @Override
  public void onStart(Application app) {
    Logger.info("Application has started");
  }  

  @Override
  public void onStop(Application app) {
    Logger.info("Application shutdown...");
  }  

}
```

This `Global` class must be located in the root of your `app` folder.

Comment: So, that means - the default package inside the App folder. Is that correct?